# TypeError: list indicies must be integers, not str

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
foo = ("PandaBears")
l = list(foo)
random.shuffle(l)
Output = ''.join(l)
print(Output)
```

I have been at this code for ages trying to figure out the problem but I have had no luck. A few hours before it was working perfectly with absolutely no trouble - `I haven't even changed / upgraded python either.`

The error is coming from

> l = list(idf)

and I have tried using `[]` instead of `()`.

Any improvements on this code would be appreciated

Comment: the code says l = list(foo). but i see l = list(idf). what is idf?

Comment: You are trying to shuffle the characters of the string?

Comment: The code as posted correctly shuffles the characters of the string. Please ensure that you verify that the code reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis are useless here:

```
foo = ("PandaBears")
```

Just write:

```
foo = "PandaBears"  # str
```

If you want a singleton `tuple`, add a trailing comma:

```
foo = ("PandaBears",)  # tuple
```

If `foo` is a string, the following statement construct a list of letters:

```
l = list(foo)
```

Don't know what is `diff`.